# Add array to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to add some arrays to another array.

Suppose I have 2 nested loops:

```
arr1 = [];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    arr1.push(i,j)
  }
}
```

I want arr1 to be

```
[[[0],[0]],[[0],[1]],[[0],[2]],[[1],[0]],...]
```

Instead I just get

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: `[[0][0]]` is not valid Javascript. Do you mean `[0, 0]` or `[[0], [0]]`?

Comment: @szym: I corrected that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Array.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) appends each argument to the array, so this is expected behavior. To accomplish what you want you should call

```
arr1.push([[i], [j]]);
```